# I want $(t+x)^n$ to be replaced with $f(n,x)$ throughout expression, what should I do?

Tags: replacement

I want $(t+x)^n$ to be replaced with some function $f(n,x)$ throughout any expression, what should I do?

Comment: Does `expression /. {(t + x)^n_ :> f[n, x], (t + x) :> f[1, x]}` what you want?

Comment: @Alx what if there is no x, just t? or t-x or x-t? Or 5 instead of x? Will it still work?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the possible ways in which the expression might appear and how each one should be replaced.

Comment: `{t + x, t, t^2, (t + 4)^6, (t - x)^3, (t + x + 1)^3} /. {(t + x_.)^n_. :> f[n, x]}`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As Michael E2 pointed out in the comments, the exponent in the rule should include the [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) (`n_.`) to cover `n == 1`

```
repl1 = (t + x)^n_. :> f[n, x];

expr1 = 3 + 5 (t + x ) + 7 (t + x)^3;

expr1 /. repl1

(* 3 + 5 f[1, x] + 7 f[3, x] *)
```

However, if `expr1` is partially expanded

```
expr2 = 3 + 5 t + 5 x + 7 (t + x)^3;

expr2 /. repl1

(* 3 + 5 t + 5 x + 7 f[3, x] *)
```

This can be handled by a temporary change of variables

```
(expr2 /. x :> z - t // Simplify) /. z -> x + t /. repl1

(* 3 + 5 f[1, x] + 7 f[3, x] *)

expr3 = 3 + 5 t + 8 x + 7 (t + x)^3;

(expr3 /. x :> z - t // Simplify) /. z -> x + t /. repl1

(* 3 - 3 t + 8 f[1, x] + 7 f[3, x] *)
```

However, this does not help with the simpler expression

```
expr4 = 3 + t + x + 7 (t + x)^3;

(expr4 /. x :> z - t // Simplify) /. z -> x + t /. repl1

(* 3 + t + x + 7 f[3, x] *)
```

Add a second rule and use [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)

```
repl2 = {(t + x)^n_. :> f[n, x], a_ + t + x :> a + f[1, x]};

expr4 //. repl2

(* 3 + f[1, x] + 7 f[3, x] *)
```

`repl2` works in the earlier cases like `repl1`

```
SameQ @@ ((expr3 /. x :> z - t // Simplify) /. z -> x + t /. # & /@ {repl1, 
    repl2})

(* True *)

SameQ @@ ((expr2 /. x :> z - t // Simplify) /. z -> x + t /. # & /@ {repl1, 
    repl2})

(* True *)

SameQ @@ (expr1 /. # & /@ {repl1, repl2})

(* True *)
```